# Implementing a Wifi-Aware application outside Android

Tags: android, linux, windows, wifi, wifip2p

So I'd like to use Wifi-Aware for a program outside the Android universe (let's assume Linux/OSX/Windows) and cannot find any info on this at all. 
At first I thought it would suffice to use a [Wifi-Aware certified](https://www.wi-fi.org/product-finder-results?sort_by=default&sort_order=desc&categories=1&keywords=wifi%20aware) product 
running one of these OSes and then implement the Wifi-Specs, but when I tried to [download](https://www.wi-fi.org/downloads-registered-guest/NeighborAwarenessNetworking_TechnicalSpecification_v2.0.pdf/29731) the specifications, I was asked to login first (but with no option of creating an account).

Do I understand correctly that you have to be a paying member of the Wifi-Alliance to even get the specifications?

Furthermore, is my assumption that, with the specification, I would be able to implement a Wifi-Aware/NAN application on say, Windows/Linux correct? Or is the specification something that is meant for OS developers and an application would rely on support from OS (like Android [provides](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-aware)) to support this? (This would then mean that it is in fact impossible to implement Wifi-Aware applications on Windows/Linux, since the OSes do not seem to support it)

Edit: There is a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1373912/is-it-possible-to-use-wifi-aware-on-windows-or-linux) on this, but it seems to have been asked from a user, not a programmer perspective, and is not going into much detail, so I do not consider this one to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need support for WiFi Aware at the hardware and the OS levels.

[The wifi.org website](https://www.wi-fi.org/news-events/newsroom/wi-fi-certified-wi-fi-aware-enhances-the-wi-fi-mobile-experience) mentions the following "certified Wi-Fi Aware devices":

- Broadcom BCM4361 11ac STA Reference Design
- Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
- Marvell 802.11ac Wave2 Wi-Fi Test Bed Evaluation Kit
- Qualcomm® mobile Wi-Fi AC2 chipset

I guess that Intel card might be your best bet? Although [the iwlwifi driver page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi) mentions that:

> While we advertise support for Wi-Fi Location* and Wi-Fi Aware* on
>   8260, we can't commmit on accurate results for those features. NAN
>   isn't considered stable yet and may or may not work depending on the
>   firmware version.

As for OS support, as far as I know that is currently limited to Android.

Comment: Deleted my previous comments and posted a more thorough answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1786039/465683), which tries to document the few available software bits.